The scroller delays (or lags) when using react-three/fiber and framer-motion
I'm trying to combine three.js content by react-three/fiber and framer-motion.
The problem is that when I use framer-motion to pin the canvas to the top, I notice a delay gap between my HTML content and the 3D content. See the GIF below:

And the expected behavior is:

Here are some findings and attempts:

When I resize the window, the issue can be fixed and it works as expected.

It's not about the size of the div; even a smaller canvas can cause the problem.

If I set the Canvas frameloop to 'never', it works as expected, but the 3D content won't show.

I simplified the environment and code on the sandbox, but the problem still occurs.

When I load the page, switch to another tab, and then return to the page, it works as expected.


You can check the sandbox of this questions here.
Do you have any solutions, or is there a problem in my code?
